# Problem with UKF weights when calculating predicted state

Tags: localization, kalman-filter, algorithm, software, motion

I'm having troubles implementing a UKF during the calculation of $\overline{\mu_t}$, specifically in this step:
$$\overline{\mu_t} = \sum_{i=0}^{2n}w_m^{[i]}\chi_t^{*[i]}$$

My problem I'm facing is that $\overline{\mu_t}$ seems to not be close to the values of the sigma points at all, and I have no idea why.

My state is composed of $x, y, v, a, \theta, \dot{\theta}$. Here is one example of an iteration:
$$\mu_{t-1} = \begin{bmatrix}2.7 \\ 8.3e-05 \\ 1 \\ 0.2 \\ 3.2e-15 \\ 1e-9 \end{bmatrix}\\
\Sigma_{t-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
   0.038&  7.6e-07&    0.013&   0.0018& -1.7e-09&  1.5e-11 \\
 7.6e-07&     0.99&    4e-07&  1.5e-07&        1&    8e-10 \\
   0.013&    4e-07&    0.005&  0.00095&  1.1e-17&  4.7e-12 \\ 
  0.00187&  1.5e-07&  0.00095&  0.00036& -1.8e-15&  5.7e-13 \\ 
-1.7e-09&        1&  1.1e-17& -1.8e-15&      1.1& -1.9e-23 \\
 1.5e-11&    8e-10&  4.7e-12&  5.7e-13& -1.9e-23&    1e-08 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The $x$ values of the sigma points after the transition model:
\begin{bmatrix}
     2.82606 &     2.85113   &    2.8251   &   2.82614   &   2.82606      2.82603 &     2.82606    &    2.801  &     2.8251 &     2.82599  &    2.82606   &  2.82603   &   2.82606
\end{bmatrix}

For my weights, I chose $\alpha$ such that weights would be integers, since I was worried that this was a floating point error:
$$w_m^{[i]} = \begin{bmatrix}-384\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\\32\end{bmatrix}$$

However, calculating $\overline{\mu_t}$ yields $-0.064$, which is evidently wrong. [Wolfram alpha confirms that this is not a floating point error](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.826064679+*+-384+%2B+32*(2.851132721%2B+2.825098207+%2B+2.826141712+%2B+2.826064684+%2B+2.826026219+%2B+2.826064679+%2B+2.800996636+%2B+2.825098206+%2B+2.825987645+%2B+2.826064673+%2B+2.826026219+%2B+2.826064679+)). I have no idea where I might be going in the calculation here.

Any idea how I would go about solving this problem?